# custom resource bundle interpolator not called

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Custom resource bundle message interpolator not called when user submits an application form page
This code was working a while ago, but later stopped working. Could it be because of pom.xml changes which has the hibernate-validator entry?

```
public class CustomResourceBundleMessageInterpolator extends
    ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator {

@Override
public String interpolate(String message, Context context) {

    String evaluatedMessage = "";
    //overwrite the hibernate validator message
}
```

validation.xml (Meta-inf/validation.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
     <message-interpolator>interpolator.CustomResourceBundleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
  </validation-config>
```

Comment: "*stopped working*" does mean? No errors/exceptions, nothing exceptional is reported, just remains totally silent?

Comment: No call to interpolate method during validation phase.